# Search Result Count

Tags: search, solspace, supersearch, update

Our client would like to have search result total(s) next to the filter options. Those numbers would update based on the filters chosen prior:

I can't upload an image, so here is a link to an example: http://ryanwake.com/super_search/filter_example.jpg

In the image - if a user chose Chemical Biology, then the total results for the other filter options would update based on the option chosen.

Has anyone done this, is it even possible with Super Search and Tags?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to update results using javascript/jQuery and AJAX, fetching the search form results from a separate template containing `{exp:super_search:results}`.

For example, calling a template containing {exp:super_search:results} and searching for both checked tags and the yet unchecked tag (eg. the checked "Chemical Biology" and unchecked "Structural Biology"), is one way to go for this.

You'll probably need an ajax call for each unchecked tag, although you might be able to get all results using one ajax call (and getting results for all tags).